# Prove that A\(A\B) is a subset of B for all subsets A and B of x

Tags: proof-writing, set-theory

Let X be a set. For subsets C and D of X, we define
C\D = { $x\in X$ : $x\in C$ but $x \notin D$ }
Prove that A(A\B) is a subset of B for all subsets A and B of X.

My try:
x∈A(A\B)is equivalent to  ∈  ∧  ∉ ∖ =>  ∈  ∧ ¬( ∈  ∧  ∉ ) =>  ∈  ∧ ( ∉  ∨  ∈ ) => ( ∈  ∧  ∉ ) ∨ ( ∈  ∧  ∈ ) =>  ∨ ( ∈  ∧  ∈ ) =>  ∈  ∧  ∈ .
Am I allowed to conclude that since  ∈  ∩  is a subset of B then the statement is proved?

Comment: Yep, that works. Maybe you want to explain why $A\cap B$ is a subset of $B$ though?

Comment: Hello ! I think there is a simpler way to do it avoiding the logical notation which is not very clear in this situation (at least for me).

Comment: @JoshuaTilley if that proves the statement then yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to show that $A\setminus (A\setminus B)$ is a subset of $B$, which means that if $x$ is an element of $A \setminus (A \setminus B)$ then $x$ is also an element of $B$. So far, your argument is shaped like this:
$$
\begin{align}
 x \in A \setminus (A \setminus B) & \implies \dots \\
   & \implies \dots \\
   & \dots \text{some more steps} \dots \\
   & \implies x \in A \wedge x \in B .
\end{align}
$$

You're asking about proving that $A \cap B$ is a subset of $B$, which means that if $x$ is an element of $A \cap B$ then it's also an element of $B$. But you are already almost there: you have $x \in A \wedge x \in B$ and you are trying to conclude $x \in B$. So it's not necessary to translate back into set-theory language for the final step.